# Executing codes in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

In my .m file :

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

/* Some codes for picker view
     and slider */

```
}
```

I used a button to navigate to second view by using the below code:

- (IBAction)goToPlay{
  [self presentModalViewController: secondViewController animated: YES];
  }

I used another button to go back to first view by using below code:

- (IBAction)goBack{
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
  Now the viewDidLoad method is not calling.  I had written some codes in viewDidLoad in first view  and I want to execute it when pressing goBack button in second view.

What should I do?

Anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}
```

method, this would be called every time your view will appear...